# Replace JavaScrip

Tags: javascript

Каким образом можно отредактировать строку в js по типу:
var text = "Name-Family-Age";

Нужно чтобы в тексте искался символ "-" и заменялся на div

Строка которая должна получаться в результате

```
<div>Name</div>
<div>Family</div>
<div>Age</div>
```

Comment: Если делаешь шаблонизатор, то правильно делать так, чтобы слово выделялось двумя одинаковыми символами.....как раз как тег.....иначе не ясно, с чего это вдруг Name и Age должны в див оборачиваться

Comment: условно, в div должно оборачиваться всё, что идёт от "-" до следующего "-", но я не силен в JS

Comment: замечательно..... тогда твоё "должно оборачиваться" идёт вразрез с тем, что в итоге должно получиться по твоему же мнению

Comment: Даже если строка будет "-Name-Family-Age" как мне обернуть?

Comment: `'<div>' + str.replaceAll('-', '</div><div>') + '</div>'`

Comment: Вначале определись что на входе должно быть и что на выходе это раз....во-вторых определись, что будет при различных ситуциях, например если два и более тире идут подряд. или будет -a-b-a-b-b-a - какой результат должен быть и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю вам подойдет такое решение:

1. Превращаем строку в массив
2. Добавляем к содержимому массива div
3. Превращаем массив в строку

```js
const str = "Name-Family-Age";
const replaceToDIV = (string) => {
  return string.split("-").map((s) => `<div>${s}</div>`).join("");
}

// <div>Name</div><div>Family</div><div>Age</div>
console.log(replaceToDIV(str));
```

Comment: `join` надо запускать не с пустой строкой, а c переходом на новую строку `"\n"`

Answer (score 0):

Вариант через регулярку:

```js
"Name-Family-Age".replace(/(\w+)-{0,1}/g, '<div>$1</div>')

// <div>Name</div><div>Family</div><div>Age</div>
```